# How to edit Identity specification in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database in SQL Server 2008. I am unable to set **Identity specification** for a column `CartId` as shown in figure

[image]

I deleted the column and tried creating a new column and set `isIdentity` property but it's not working, also I deleted the table and tried creating a new table (not using query) but not able to set `isIdentity` property

How to fix this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Type of column must be set to `INTEGER` or other numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

identity property available only on numeric columns