# Identity specification in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to set identity specification  for a column in `SQL Server 2008`? I also need to set the seed as "ST000".

Please help me.

Comment: You can't set the seed as `ST000`. `IDENTITY` columns are numeric. Are you only ever expecting this table to have `<=1000` rows?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900065/how-to-edit-identity-specification-in-sql-server-2008 may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ....other columns here.....
```

Just use the `IDENTITY` keyword - you can specify a seed (starting value) and an increment - typically, both are set to `1` (but they don't have to).

For more details, see the [MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for `IDENTITY`

If you need to have a **non-numeric column** that sort of behaves like an `IDENTITY`, I'd suggest you use the above approach, and then define an extra column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  IDwithPrefix AS 'ST' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED,

  ....other columns here.....
```

That way, your `ID` column will automatically get values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....... and the `IDwithPrefix` column will have `ST0001`, `ST0002` and so forth.