# how to automatically manage the serial number in a database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created an application in vb.net which accepts values from the user and inserts them into the database (created in SQL server 2008). It accepts the name, address, phone numbers, etc from the application itself. But the problem is, the user also needs to enter the serial number into the application. Is there a way to manage the serial number automatically? Because no one remembers the serial number of the last record. So, one needs to check the serial number of the last record in the database every time before assigning the serial number for the new record.

I also want that if any record is deleted from the middle of the database, the serial number should be adjusted automatically. So, what I want is, the serial numbers should be assigned automatically like 1 for the first record, 2 for the next, 3,4,5,6... and so on. But if the record corresponding to the serial number 5 is deleted, then the s.no. 6 should become s.no. 5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If, the so called 'serial number' is just a sequential number assigned to every record to unique identify that record then just use IDENTITY columns and forget the resequencing part. A 'serial number' once assigned should never change.

Comment: Following Steve indication, here you can find some detail on how to set it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900065/how-to-edit-identity-specification-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: The serial number is actually displayed to the user on the view all records section of the application. So, the user may also use this to count the number of records. That's why I'm concerned about the correct numbering of the records. Basically, I don't want to send the value of this particular field from the application itself. Rather I want the value to be assigned automatically. And, I have already defined phone no. as the primary key for the table.

Comment: sql has a count function you can use to count the number of records.

Comment: Phone number is a bad choice for a primary key for two reasons.  One, it can change.  Two, it can be shared by more than one person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to call one function every time you register a record on database. Before assigning record no check last number on database and add a count and save the same number as serial number. In the database create a column with serial_no as a Primary key,

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
Serial_no int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Serial_no)
);
```

and sorry Im not much familiar with VB, here Im providing solution in C# and I hope you get an idea with this piece of code.

```
public void create_serial_no()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_database_name"].ConnectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT [Serial_no] FROM table_name";
        connection.Open();
        string strs = command.CommandText;
        string i = null;
        int j = 0;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
                i = reader["Serial_no"].ToString(); ;
        }
        j = Convert.ToInt32(i);
        int k = 0;

        k = j + 1;
        // this is a serial no generated automaticall by the database
        textBox1.Text = k.ToString();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!